# Kotlin Firebase foreach child in path

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple to-do app in Kotlin and I want to get data from "task" node in firebase on app startup. For each child, I want to create a Todo object.

[image]

```
var todo = Todo("child data here")
```

Getting specific task

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val ref = database.getReference("task")
var todo = ref.child("task1").key?.let { Todo(it) }
if (todo != null) {
     todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
}
```

Comment: So what exactly would you like to read? Only the values of those three children, which are `task1`, `task2` and `task3`?

Comment: Can you share your code? Do you know how to fetch from Firebase already and you just want to create a Todo object for each? Or you need help with fetching and creating the objects?

Comment: It sounds like you want to loop over the child nodes of a snapshot as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to get all children, there can be more than three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get all children, there can be more than three.

If you want to get all children of a particular node, no matter how many are actually present there, then you should loop over that node using `getChildren()` method, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val taskRef = db.child("task")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val value = ds.getValue(String::class.java)
            Log.d("TAG", value)

            //Create the desired object
            var todo = Todo(value) //
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()) //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
taskRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
task1
task2
task3
.....
```